# How do I specify a non-negative number at the type level, if I shouldn't be using unsigned?

Tags: c++, function, types, interface, integer

In a [Going Native 2013](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything) talk,  the panel had suggested avoiding unsigned integer types
when specifying variables that "can't be negative".

> 12:15:  "Use signed integers unless you need 2's compliment arithmetic or a bit
>   pattern."

---

> 12:55: "Use ints until you have a reason not to.   Don't use unsigned unless
>   you are fiddling with bit patterns, and never mix signed and unsigned."

---

> 42:45: "Whenever you mix signed and unsigned numbers you get trouble.  The
>   rules are just very surprising, and they turn up in code in the
>   strangest places.  They correlate very strongly with bugs.   When
>   people use unsigned integer numbers, they usually have a reason.   The
>   reason will be something like "well, it can't be negative" ... When
>   you think you can't have negative numbers, you will have someone who
>   initializes your unsigned with -2, and think they get -2.  It is just
>   highly error prone. ...  There are far too many integer types.  There
>   are far too lenient rules for mixing them together, and it's a major
>   bug source.   Which is why I'm saying, stay as simple as you can.  Use
>   integers until you really really need something else."

This is understood, but there is no mention to alternatives when designing interfaces that must only accept positive numbers.  I could document it:

```
//NOTE: i must be positive!
void function(int i);
```

I could rely on debug assertions everywhere:

```
void function(int i){
  assert(i >= 0);
}
```

What I'd really like, is to specify it at the type level.  This is a stronger contract.  I want to make sure the function is incapable of accepting an integer that is negative.  This is where I would normally choose an unsigned, but given that this is a discouraged practice, what are my alternatives?

Can a type like this be created to satisfy the value constraint?

```
void function(positive<int> i);
```

Does it make sense to do this?

Comment: 12.55 **"never mix signed and unsigned"** and the use of std::size_t (size_type) in the standard C++ library, leads to: Always (!) use unsigned integers for indices and sizes (in terms of capacity of a container).

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes, the panel addresses that.  They agree that unsigned indexes in the STL was a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why having the parameter `unsigned` solves nothing is because passing a run-time negative value into such a function checks nothing. `-1` will be reinterpreted as `4294967295` and the program will silently continue.

Only if you try to pass a compile-time known constant a warning will be raised.

If you want to check every parameter you pass into your function, even at run-time, having an assert is the simplest way.

If you want to be more fancy and descriptive, you can define your own type `positive` which would:

- allow silent casts to `int` (demotion)
- allow casts from `int`, but performing an `assert` when doing so (promotion)
- support arithmetic operations

This will definitely make your code ``cleaner'' with a clear intent - but that is much more coding.

Answer (score 0):

But it is technically impossible to prevent negative values from being passed because only by running the code can you enumerate through the function's argument range.

Run-time assertions should be fine as you can remove them from a release build. This is normal practice, even in complicated codes for example from CGAL:

```
template<class Inter_pt_coplanar,class Point_3,class Halfedge_handle>
std::pair<Inter_pt_coplanar,Inter_pt_coplanar>
decision_tree(const Point_3* a,const Point_3* b,const Point_3* c,
              const Point_3* p,const Point_3* q,
              const Orientation& pqa,const Orientation& pqb,const Orientation& pqc,
              Halfedge_handle pq,
              Halfedge_handle ca,Halfedge_handle ab,Halfedge_handle bc)
{
  CGAL_precondition(pqa!=NEGATIVE);
  CGAL_precondition(pqb!=NEGATIVE);
  CGAL_precondition(pqc!=POSITIVE);
```

http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/devman_checks.html

Comment: Fair enough.  This seems like the right approach until C++ adopts some form of preconditions.