# Getting the class variables from .h file, in the .cpp file

Tags: c++

I'm quite new to C++, and I have a problem with my class definition. This is most likely a pretty basic operation, but I can't find any relevant resources online, as I'm not quite sure what to search for.

The title says it all. I have a header file looking like the following:

```
class Rectangle{
public:
    int Width();
    int Height();
    int Area();
    void Resize();
private:
    int width;
    int height;
}
```

And then I have the following .cpp file.

```
int Rectangle::Width()
{
    //return the width
}

int Rectangle::Height()
{
    //return the height
}

int Rectangle::Area()
{
    //return the area
} 

void Rectangle::Resize()
{
    //resize the rectangle
}
```

As you can see, I have commented the operations that I wish to do, but I am not quite sure how to access the variables `int width` and `int height` from the header file.

Comment: Did you include the header file in the cpp file?

Comment: Just a heads-up: you are missing a `;` after your class definition.

Comment: You need to include the header file, and make sure that there is a semicolon following the last curly brace of the class definition.

Comment: I already have the `;` after my definition. Just didn't copy paste. I have included the header file, I simply don't know how to access the variables.

Comment: You may want to use `unsigned int` for height and width.  Regular `int` can go negative.  In my life experience, I haven't come across negative heights or widths, but I'm open to seeing a rectangle with negative width or height.  Same with area.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Bad advice.  You shouldn't use `unsigned` unless you need 2's compliment arithmetic or a bit pattern.

Comment: @TrevorHickey:  So for quantities, how can they be negative?  I want to ask the grocer for -6 apples, but I'm not sure what I will get.  If I use `unsigned`, then the compiler can assist in finding those cases where quantities are accidentally assigned negative numbers.  Also, the `unsigned` has a greater positive range than the signed version.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The information in this question will help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717573/how-do-i-specify-a-non-negative-number-at-the-type-level-if-i-shouldnt-be-usin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is make sure you include the `class` header file at the top of your `.cpp` like so...

```
#include "THE_FILE_NAME.h"
```

Then you can access them as you wish. For example, to return the width and height just do:

```
int Rectangle::Width()
{
    return width; //or this->width
}

int Rectangle::Height()
{
    return height; //or this->height
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: These *getters* and *setters* may be more efficient by placing them in the header file, allowing the compiler to inline them.  (Yes, I know that the compiler could inline them anyways.)

Answer (score 2):

Like so.

```
int Rectangle::Width()
{
  return this->width;  // or `return width;`
}
```

**Note** Also please remember to add a [header guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) at the top of your `.h` file.  And at the top of your `.cpp` file add a `#include "header.h"` where `header.h` should be replaced with the name of the header file with the class definition

Comment: This is neat as well. Why not use `this->` @NathanOliver? I'd like you to elaborate for me :)

Comment: @NathanOliver Just my personal preference

Comment: @NathanOliver the `this` keyword is a pointer reference to the current class object, therefore to access its variables, you must use the pointer accessor operator `->`

Comment: @m_callens I know what `this` is.  I asked as it is completly unneeded as there is no name hiding going on.

Comment: @NathanOliver oh, my mistake! I typically don't use `this->` either but its an option I guess

Comment: @NathanOliver I feel like people may disagree with me here, but I use `this` over naming conventions like `mMember` just to be explicit

Comment: Standard `#pragma once` warning. This isn't standard C++. The common compilers support it, but if a compiler doesn't recognize a `#pragma` it is allowed to **silently discard it**. Be certain your compiler, and all the compilers you may have to support, implement `once` and implement it the same way. Otherwise you're in for some nasty surprises.

Comment: Usually the `this->` pointer syntax is used to differentiate between method parameters and class members, *when they have the same name*.  The `this->` notation requires more typing and increases the injection of defects.  I give my parameters and data members different names so I don't need to use the `this->` notation.

Comment: @user4581301 I never knew that!  I use it freely all the time.  Maybe I need to rethink that

Answer (score 0):

Yes,what they said is truth.

However if you let me give you an advise, 
Everytime you have a private variable you want to have get/set functions.
Get will return the value of the desired variable
Set will assign any value you want.

```
enter code here    
///Set
 void setWidth(int x){
 width=x;
 }

 //Get
int getwidth(){
  return width;
}
```